# Login a user using PassportJS after creating using SailsJS Blueprint API

Tags: sails.js, passport.js

How to login a user using PassportJS after the user has been created using Blueprint API. I have no access to create action. Also the lifecycle callback `afterCreate` does not provide request object which is needed by Passport to call `req.login()`?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem. It would be nice if you also have some example code.

Answer (score 0):

You do have access to the create action and the user it provides. In your controller, you can do this:

```
createAndLogin: function (req, res) {
    User.create(req.body.user)
        .then(function (user) {
            // Log in with passport;
            req.login(user, myCallback);
        })
}
```

...where `myCallback` would be a function to return a res.success or res.500 based on the result.

(Sails supports promise syntax, which I prefer, but you can use the callback model with the `.create()` method as well.)